# toastr shows only after I refresh the page just for one condition

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, toastr

I am using the following line to display toastr success message. But there is one condition where this line is being hit but toastr is not getting displayed and it works when the page is refreshed.

```
this._toastr.success('Data Saved successfully');
```

Comment: Are you sure that this condition is met? If it works 99% of the time, usually the issue can be found in the 1% where is doesn't work. If you are sure that this line is the error, you should at least provide some more code for us to gather information.

Comment: yes this condition is met and the only problem is toastr is not getting displayed but the above mentioned line is getting called. I tried with opacity:1 but no outcome from it. If I refresh the page then the toastr is displayed.

Comment: you should add more code to narrow down the issue. Is there any error in the console? What type is `_toastr` property? Is it contained in a service or a component?